# InnoDB: duplicate indixes found - is this very bad?

Tags: mysql, magento

recently our Magento store has become extremely slow. We dont really know why.

Just today I noticed when I did a database check **that more than 900 indexes are identical duplicates**, i.e. two exist.

**My question is**: hoe can this impact performance? + if it does, how would I go about deleting one of the two.

Thanks, Sean

EXAMPLE

> Problemen met The indexes van de tabel `mag_eav_form_fieldset_label`
>   The indexes IDX_MAG_EAV_FORM_FIELDSET_LABEL_STORE_ID en IDX_GALI_EAV_FORM_FIELDSET_LABEL_STORE_ID look the same, possibly one of both can be deleted.
>   The indexes IDX_MAG_EAV_FORM_FIELDSET_LABEL_FIELDSET_ID en IDX_GALI_EAV_FORM_FIELDSET_LABEL_FIELDSET_ID look the same, possibly one of both can be deleted.
>   The indexes IDX_MAG_EAV_FORM_FIELDSET_LABEL_STORE_ID en IDX_EAV_FORM_FIELDSET_LABEL_STORE_ID look the same, possibly one of both can be deleted.
>   The indexes IDX_MAG_EAV_FORM_FIELDSET_LABEL_FIELDSET_ID en IDX_EAV_FORM_FIELDSET_LABEL_FIELDSET_ID look the same, possibly one of both can be deleted.
>   Problemen met The indexes van de tabel `mag_eav_form_type`
>   The indexes IDX_MAG_EAV_FORM_TYPE_STORE_ID en IDX_GALI_EAV_FORM_TYPE_STORE_ID look the same, possibly one of both can be deleted.
>   The indexes IDX_MAG_EAV_FORM_TYPE_STORE_ID en IDX_EAV_FORM_TYPE_STORE_ID look the same, possibly one of both can be deleted.
>   The indexes UNQ_MAG_EAV_FORM_TYPE_CODE_THEME_STORE_ID en UNQ_GALI_EAV_FORM_TYPE_CODE_THEME_STORE_ID look the same, possibly one of both can be deleted.
>   The indexes UNQ_MAG_EAV_FORM_TYPE_CODE_THEME_STORE_ID en UNQ_EAV_FORM_TYPE_CODE_THEME_STORE_ID look the same, possibly one of both can be deleted.
>   Problemen met The indexes van de tabel `mag_eav_form_type_entity`
>   The indexes IDX_MAG_EAV_FORM_TYPE_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID en IDX_GALI_EAV_FORM_TYPE_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID look the same, possibly one of both can be deleted.

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to delete them safely, i suggest you to use pt-duplicate-key-checker in Percona toolkit. It will generate the drop index SQL for you automatically.

Too many indexes do decrease performance, especially for update and insert.
You would better drop those useless indexes.

Comment: Ok thx. And how would I knwo which are Magento original and keeping those (thereby not breaking any future updates).

Comment: Idea. Is there an DROP ALL INDEXES statement? This way I start with 0 and can then crosscheck with a fresh install.

Comment: ISP won't install percona. Other tricks?

Answer (score 0):

I posted an update to Magento DB repair tool here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

It now also removes indexes that are NOT found in the reference database

Comment: I know this is years later, but your tool is not removing indexes that do not exist in the reference database on 1.9.1  -  Any advice? I'm having same issue as original poster. same with foreign keys

Comment: Page was changed. Script Seems gone. Sorry.

Comment: Script 1.2 is only available

Comment: do you have a copy of the old script?  1.2 is only available on magento